# Understanding the question from Shiryaev: $B_m$ be the event in which each of the events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ occurs exactly $m$ times

Tags: probability

§2, exercise 5, p.17:

> Let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be events, and define $S_0,S_1,\dots,S_n$ as
>   follows: $S_0=1$
>   $$\begin{alignedat}{1}\begin{split}S_{r}=\sum_{J_{r}}P\left(A_{k_{1}}\cap\cdots\cap
> > A_{k_{r}}\right),\end{split}  & 1\leq r\leq n\end{alignedat}$$ where
>   the sum is over the unordered subsets
>   $J_{r}=\left[k_{1},\dots,k_{r}\right]$ of $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\}$
>   .
>
> Let $B_m$ be the event in which each of the events $A_1,\dots,A_n$
>   occurs exactly $m$ times. Show that
>   $$P\left(B_{m}\right)=\sum_{r=m}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{r-m}C_{r}^{m}S_{r}$$

I don't understand what $B_m$ is!? (my understandings lead to wrong result, tested with particular values of $m$, and $n$)

The original Russian texts:

> Пусть $B_{m}$ - событие, состоящее в том, что одновременно произойдет в точности $m$ событий из $A_{1},\dots,A_{n}$.

What is the Russian texts actual meaning? (I want to know if there was problem with translation or it's my fault)

I found an answer from a [German forum](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=de&sp=nmt4&u=https://matheraum.de/forum/Englischer_Aufgabentext/t833238&usg=ALkJrhgqOvjug0tb5a_yamkLtj0Dn5zxVg), which said that:

> (google translator): This is indeed a bit incomprehensible, because here m * n events are combined into one

but, I don't know how to interpret the question like that.

---

**P/S:**
I found an answer, my question could be marked as duplicated: [The Probability $P_{[m]}$ that exactly $m$ among the $N$ events $A_1,\dots,A_N$ occur simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716775/the-probability-p-m-that-exactly-m-among-the-n-events-a-1-dots-a-n?rq=1)

Indeed, I found that the combined result of the online translators (Google, Yandex, Bing, PROMT) is closed to the exercise posted in the link above:

> machine translation: Let $B_{m}$ be the event, which consists simultaneous occurrence of exactly $m$ events of $A_{1},\dots,A_{n}$

Comment: You may find more rigorous to define $B_m$ as $$B_m=\{N_n=m\}$$ where $$N_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf 1_{A_k}$$

Comment: What is the notation: $1_{A_{k}}$? I don't know!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Thanks, in this book it's $I_{A_{k}}$