# Understanding "The distribution of the Number of Events that Occur"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Just as the title, it is 2.7 in Ross's book (Introduction to Probability Models).

Consider arbitrary events A1,...,An, and let X denote the number if these events that occur. We will determine the probability mass function of X. To begin, for 1<= k <= n, let

$S_k$ = $\sum_{i_1<...<i_k} P(A_{i1}...A_{ik})$

....

Finally, it proves
P(X>=k) = $\sum_{j=k}^n (-1)^{k+j} {j-1\choose {k-1}}S_j$

I had no idea what does "The distribution of the Number of Events that Occur" means?

Edit:

a) What does the expansion of $S_k$ looks like? like $\sum_i P(E_i E_j E_k E_l)$ in $P(E_1\bigcup E_2 \bigcup ... \bigcup E_n)$  =  $\sum_i P(E_i)$ - $\sum_i P(E_i E_j)$ + $\sum_i P(E_i E_j E_k)$ - $\sum_i P(E_i E_j E_k E_l)$ + ... + $(-1)^{n+1} P(E_i E_j ... E_n) $

b) Does it has a countable sample space?

Please give me an example about such a topic, any reference are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Related question:

[The Probability $P_{[m]}$ that exactly $m$ among the $N$ events $A_1,\dots,A_N$ occur simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716775/the-probability-p-m-that-exactly-m-among-the-n-events-a-1-dots-a-n?rq=1)

Comment: It means the distribution of the random variable $X$ which is defined as the number of events $A_i$ which occur. For example, suppose $n=2.$ If neither $A_1$ nor $A_2$ occurs, then $X=0;$ if $A_1$ and $A_2$ both occur, then $X=2;$ if $A_1$ occurs but $A_2$ does not occur, or if $A_2$ occurs but $A_1$ does not occur, then $X=1.$

Comment: @bof  In case of your example, what is the range of X? [0,2]?

Comment: The number of occurrences is a discrete variable, its range is $\{0,1,\dots,n\}.$ If $n=3$ the range of $X$ is $\{0,1,2\}.$

Comment: You should check out [the Bonferroni inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities), and the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability). Specifically, read the special case section of the second link, noting that because we are looking at $P[X\geq k]$ we don't care which events occur, only that there are at least $k$ of them, and thus this gives us the binomial coefficients through the special case.

Comment: @bof Thanks. So X represents types of distinct events that occurred?

Comment: @RyanWarnick Thank you very much.

Comment: Which chapter? I don't see the materials you mentioned in 2.7.

Comment: @Jack My text is 11th edition. it is section 2.7. The previous section 2.6 is Moment Generating Functions, and the next section 2.8 is Limit Theorems.