# Using Inclusion-Exclusion, probability of occurrence of exactly $m$ events out of $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, prove that the probability of occurrence of exactly $m$ events out of $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-m} (-1)^i   \binom{m+i}{m} P_{m+i} $ where $P_k = \sum_{1 \leq i_1<\cdots \le i_k \leq n} P(A_{i_1} \cap\cdots \cap A_{i_k})$

**Attempt:**  I was trying to understand this term on the RHS : $\binom{m+i}{m} P_{m+i}$. And then the inclusion-exclusion principle shall follow.

**This is what I thought to be able to use inclusion-exclusion but I am not very sure if this is the right approach.**

$m$ events can occur either from the first $m$ events, or from the first $m+1$ events, or from the first $m+2$ events, $\cdots$, or from the n events.

$$E_k = \text{the $m$ events occur from the first $m+k$ events}$$

Then $P(E_k) = \binom{m+k}{m} \sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots i_m\leq m+k} P(A_{i_1} \cap \cdots  \cap A_{i_m})$

But, then I could not move forward from here. I tried understanding the solution given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716775/the-probability-p-m-that-exactly-m-among-the-n-events-a-1-dots-a-n), but I would really appreciate something more intuitive.

Could someone please explain how do I move forward from here?

Comment: Do you know what is $r$?

Comment: @user sorry. typo mistake. edited it

Comment: There is still another one.

Comment: @user done now ..

Comment: The $\bigcap$ symbol is used in things like $\bigcap_i A_i$ or $\displaystyle\bigcap_i A_i$ and the $\cap$ symbol in things like $A\cap B$ or $A_1\cap \cdots\cap A_n.$ I edited accordingly. I also changed the first expression below to the second: $$ \begin{align} & E_k = \text{the m events occur from the first m+k events} \\ {} \\ & E_k = \text{the $m$ events occur from the first $m+k$ events} \end{align} $$ I.e. both the isolated $m$ and $m+k$ look different. The first expression is considered incorrect usage according to standard conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered a marvelous proof. However, since it's long, I haven't been able to type it. Posting clear images for the sake of anyone who might be searching for the same answer.[image][image][image]